# Body background color appearing in whole site divs

Tags: css, html

Many times have faced this problem in creating full background through `body` tag. If the `body` tag has background blue than all small `div` in website will show same color. Even main `div` background not working. In this situation i'm making particularly all `div background-none` . Please tell me if there is any idea to solve this problem.

```
<header><div class="inner">
        <div class="h-top"><div class="left blue-text">Traditional Print • Social Syndication • Embedded Video • Radio</div> <div class="right"> (800)355-9500 <img src="images/in.png" alt="" align="absmiddle" title="linkedin.com"  />  <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="" align="absmiddle" title="twitter.com"  /> <img src="images/facebook.png" align="absmiddle" alt="" title="facebook.com"  /> <img src="images/bloger.png" alt="" align="absmiddle" title="linkedin.com"  /></div></div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="h-bottom"><div class="left"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" title="" /></div>
        <nav class="right"> 
            <ul>          
                <li>Our Guarantee</li>
                <li> Our Difference  </li>
                <li>What We Do </li>
                <li> Our Clients </li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div><!--h-bottom-->

      </div><!--inner-header-->    
    </header>





*{

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-style:normal;
    color:#011c2d;
    font-size:17px;
    background:#d2d2d2;
    font-family:'schoolbookregular';
}

.main{
    width:1082px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#f5f5f5;
}

.inner{
    margin:0 50px;
}

.left{
    float:left;
}

.right{
    float:right;
}

.h-top{
    padding:20px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.blue-text{
    color:#0067b0;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.h-bottom{
    margin: 20px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

header{
    font-family:'schoolbookregular';
}

nav{
    margin:17px 0 0 0;
}

nav>ul{
    marigh:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav>ul>li{
    float:left;
    padding:7px 15px;
    margin-left:7px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#0067b0;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Add some html. And what is your problem exactly. That's how css works. You got to style the div's. Cant help without your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the body background, do it explicitly with

```
body {
    background: #d2d2d2;
}
```

You shouldn’t set the background of `*`, this usually causes a lot of overwriting, which isn’t nice.

Comment: But we can use `*` on place of `body` tag. Means whats wrong with `*`

Comment: `*` means _every element_, but you shouldn’t add background color and similar stuff to every element, because most of them normally have a transparent background and therefore also show the background color of the element behind them.

Comment: Thanks @rauberdaniel, I think thats a correct definition of `*` tag i didn't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is by default your .main height will be 0, so you are not able to see any output.
Try changing the height to 500px or some value you prefer.

```
/*If you want a background color to body do it here, not on '*' */
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: #0000ff;
}

.main {
    /* other styles */
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to resolve is introduce a new 'div' tag in your page without content.
this will help you..!